# Development platform for 2D web and mobile games

Tags: 2d, physics, mobile, web

Is there a game development platform -- similar to Torque, or Unity -- which can be used to deploy 2D games on the following platforms:

- Web
- iOs
- Android
- Xbox Live Arcade (Preferred but not required)

And which has an integrated or mature physics engine? Perhaps, even a built in editor?

I've looked at the following possibilities but I've found something missing in each one. Of course in each case I may be guilty of misconception.

- Corona SDK (No web deployment, no windows support)
- Torque 2D (No web deployment)
- Flash + Flash Punk or Flixel (No native android deployment, and I'm not sure if it is stable on mobile platforms)
- Unity + SpriteManager2 (Not really optimised for 2D games, and I haven't seen enough advanced 2D examples -- like say platformers -- to really have any confidence in using it for something like this)

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Unity.  At worst you could write your own sprite management solution and you'll get the platform deployment you want.  The only other real solution is writing your own, but that's hardly a solution.

Comment: +1 - Unity will save at least a person-year of work here, if you need to target all those platforms. Flash + Flixel is the only alternative I'd consider, and that won't port to XBLA nor work _well_ on mobiles. (No fault of Flixel's.)

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d may be an option. There are some recent projects for it that have ported the API to most of the platforms you've specified aside from XBLA. It won't be a write-once, run anywhere sort of thing though. You'll need to convert it to the language for each platform, unless you use the C++ port but that won't get you on the web.

- [iOS](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) (Objective-C)
- [Android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/) (Java)
- [Web](http://www.cocos2d-javascript.org/) (Javascript)
- [PC, iOS, Android](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) (C++)

I've only used the iOS version, but it has Box2D packaged with it for physics. I'm not sure about its integration on other platforms.